# Decode UTF16 encoded string (URL) in Java Script

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-16

I have string that is encoded in UTF16 and i want to decode it using JS, when i use simple [decodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)
function i get the desired result but in case when special characters are there in the string like á, ó, etc it do not decodes.
On more analysis i came to know that these characters in the encoded string contains the ASCII value.

Say I have string "Acesse já, Encoded version : "Acesse%20j%E1". How can i get the string from the encode version using java script?

EDIT:
The string is a part of URL

Comment: What do you mean by “decode UTF-16 strings”? JS strings are already UTF-16

Comment: I am getting some encoded string "Acesse%20j%E1" but when i try to decode it using decodeURI(), i am not getting any result.
How can i decode it?
UTF16 is just i found while i was searching for the type of encoding toi the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your string seems to have been encoded using `escape`, use `unescape` to decode it!

```
unescape('Acesse%20j%E1');              // => 'Acesse já'
```

However, `escape` and `unescape` are deprecated, you’d better use `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` here.

```
encodeURIComponent('Acesse já');        // => 'Acesse%20j%C3%A1'
decodeURIComponent('Acesse%20j%C3%A1'); // => 'Acesse já'
```